# In illustrator how do I create a clipping mask path based on a path layer?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

I am trying to apply a pattern piece of vector artwork which is from one image to another image.

The original image has the following:

[image]

it has a clip group - with a clipping path and a artwork splatter layer - which contains a splatter set of artwork seen - which extends far beyond the faded purple rectangular outline you can see - but doesnt show because of the clipping path.

I want to recreate this - on the following image.

In this I have the following:

[image]

I have a group which contains a path - which is the blue rectangular outline. I also have copied the artwork splatter layer from the file where the above example comes from into group called Splatter artwork.

I want to turn my 'path' layers in this second image into clipping masks where I can then add my splatter artwork layer inside of the clipping mask layer but I cannot work out how to do this - my paths cannot contain other layers it seems, not sure why.

I am very new to illustrator - so please help. I hope you understand the problem my explanation is probably pretty bad - but basically I want to emulate the clipping mask outline of the path as per the first shape in the first example - in my second image - the rectangular shape is subtly different hence why I need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try using the Pathfinder tool as well. This gives you a lot of flexibility when it comes to which direction you go without having to rearrange your layers. [image: Adobe Illustrator Pathfinder Options]

Comment: Hi Wheezykw, that is one of the nicest Pathfinder overviews I've ever seen. Welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer! If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Well i figured it out. You put the path higher in the layers than the pattern, then select both, right click and make clipping mask. Voila!